# javascript to intercept the various keys on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android

I know that it might not be possible, but I would still like to ask if you could use javascript to intercept the various keys on mobile devices. Such as (volume-up, volume-down, back) etc.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volumechange_event